# zingcharts legend adjustLayout property not doing anything?

Tags: jquery, layout, graph, legend

I'm using zingcharts to create a graph.  My graph has a legend with a lot of entries, and it is overlapping quite a bit with my graph.

going through the api i read

adjustLayout : Forces the plotarea to consider the legend positioning and prevent overlapping with it.

that sounds perfect.. I set it to true, and nothing happens.  wtf.  anyone have experience with this?

```
{
        "gui":{
          "behaviors":[
              {
                  "id": "SaveAsImage",
                  "text": "Save As Image",
                  "function": "exportimageurl"
              }
          ]

        },
        "graphset":[
        {
            "type":"mixed",
            "background-color":"#E6E6E6",
            "stacked":"0",
            "plotarea":{
                "margin":"'.$margin.'"
            },
            "title":{
                "text":"'.$title.'",
                "align":"center",
                "font-family":"Arial",
                "font-size":"18px",
                "font-color":"#000000",
                "font-weight":"bold",
                "background-color":"#E6E6E6"
            },
            "legend":{
                                    "adjustLayout": true,
                "position":"50% 100%",
                "margin":"30 3 5 3",
                "layout":"x2",
                "font-family":"arial",
                "font-size":"8px",
                "background-color":"#E6E6E6",
                "toggle-action":"remove",
                "width":"435px",
                "item":{
                    "marker-style":"square",
                    "font-color":"#000000",
                    "border-width":"0px"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the JSON you provided to make a ZingChart (added some series data, removed GUI objects for simplicity and removed attributes relying on variables):

```
    {
        "graphset":[
            {
            "type":"bar",
            "background-color":"#E6E6E6",
            "stacked":"0",
            "plotarea":{

            },
            "title":{
                "text":"X",
                "align":"center",
                "font-family":"Arial",
                "font-size":"18px",
                "font-color":"#000000",
                "font-weight":"bold",
                "background-color":"#E6E6E6"
            },
            "legend":{
                "adjustLayout":true,
                "position":"50% 100%",
                "margin":"30 3 5 3",
                "layout":"x2",
                "font-family":"arial",
                "font-size":"8px",
                "background-color":"#E6E6E6",
                "toggle-action":"remove",
                "width":"435px",
                "item":{
                    "marker-style":"square",
                    "font-color":"#000000",
                    "border-width":"0px"
                }
            },
                "series":[
            {
                "values":[69,68,54,48,70,74,98,70,72,68,49,69],
                "text":"Apple"
            },
            {
                "values":[51,53,47,60,48,52,75,52,55,47,60,48],
                "text":"Microsoft"
            },
            {
                "values":[42,43,30,40,31,48,55,46,48,32,38,38],
                "text":"Oracle"
            },
            {
                "values":[25,15,26,21,24,26,33,25,15,25,22,24],
                "text":"Dell"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

The "adjustLayout" attribute worked in LEGEND when the "margin" attribute was removed from PLOTAREA.  That is the biggest difference between the code you shared and what we've shared in this post.